# How to Count every element in an Array and create a key/value object for every item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array like:

`let myArray = ["Dennis", "Mike", "Emily", "Dennis", "John", "Jonathan", "Winston", "Melissa", "Loraine", "Tony", "Furio", "John", "Mike", "John"]`

I want to count every item in this array and put them in an array like:

```js
let countedItems = 
[
{value: "Dennis", count: 2},
{value: "Mike", count: 2},
{value: "Emily", count: 1},
{value: "Dennis", count: 1},
{value: "John", count: 3},
...
]
```

Any ideas on creating this?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let myArray = ["Dennis", "Mike", "Emily", "Dennis", "John", "Jonathan", "Winston", "Melissa", "Loraine", "Tony", "Furio", "John", "Mike", "John"]

let countedItems = myArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] ? acc[cur].count ++ : acc[cur] = {
    value: cur,
    count: 1
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(countedItems);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's great, Brilliant!

Comment: I just updated answer again.

Comment: impressive. So readable and right to the point. I guess I should do more "reduce()" exercises.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```
    const arr = ["Dennis", "Mike", "Emily", "Dennis", "John", "Jonathan", "Winston", "Melissa", "Loraine", "Tony", "Furio", "John", "Mike", "John"]
    const result = arr.reduce((p,c)=> {
        const obj = p.filter(x=> x.value == c)[0];
        if(obj){
            obj.count +=1;
        } else {
            p.push({value:c,count:1})
        }
        return p;
    },[])
```

**Update:**

```
const result = Object.entries(
                 arr.reduce((p,c)=>{
                 p[c]=p[c]?p[c]+1:1;
                 return p},{})
               ).map(x=>({value:x[0],count:x[1]}))
```

Comment: That worked amazing too!

Comment: Regarding the performance, Array.filter is called as array length times. filter() method actually iterate the array, so, the performance for this answer is O(n*n)

Comment: @William Wang, great insight! Performance is important.

Comment: Thanks, dear William Wang, for a very good point mentioned but this syntax, is more readable

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const myArray = [
  'Dennis',
  'Mike',
  'Emily',
  'Dennis',
  'John',
  'Jonathan',
  'Winston',
  'Melissa',
  'Loraine',
  'Tony',
  'Furio',
  'John',
  'Mike',
  'John',
];

const map = new Map();
myArray.forEach((x) => {
  if (map.has(x)) {
    const obj = map.get(x);
    obj.count += 1;
    map.set(x, obj);
  } else map.set(x, { value: x, count: 1 });
});
const ret = Array.from(map, ([, y]) => y);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: That worked great too. How could i miss .map()!

Comment: @Noexceptions it is not a map method. Map object is a collection of keyed data items. Check the above link in the description.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I guess I got a lot to learn. I checked the description. It is describing exactly what I was asking amazing.